# XNA Get Mesh value of Y at value of X Reply

Tags: c#, xna, xna-4.0

I am having trouble trying to get a loaded meshes value of Y at a value of X in order to perform some very limited version of detection.  Essentially, I am going to get the value of X of a camera and detect if the Y value of my mesh is 5 for example.  If so.. there is a wall there.

I load my model with this:

landscape = Content.Load("landscape");

I draw the model with this:

```
      foreach (ModelMesh mesh in landscape.Meshes)
        {
            if (mesh.Name != "Billboards")
            {
                foreach (BasicEffect effect in mesh.Effects)
                {
                    effect.View = view;
                    effect.Projection = projection;

                    effect.LightingEnabled = true;

                    effect.DirectionalLight0.Enabled = true;
                    effect.DirectionalLight0.Direction = lightDirection;
                    effect.DirectionalLight0.DiffuseColor = lightColor;

                    //if (flashEnabled == true)
                    //{
                        effect.DirectionalLight1.Enabled = flashEnabled;

                        effect.DirectionalLight1.Direction = cameraFront;
                        effect.DirectionalLight1.DiffuseColor = lightColor;
                        effect.DirectionalLight1.SpecularColor = colorFlashLight.ToVector3();
                    //}


                    effect.AmbientLightColor = ambientLightColor;

                    effect.FogEnabled = fogEnabled;
                    effect.FogColor = color.ToVector3();
                    effect.FogStart = 9.75f;
                    effect.FogEnd = 10.25f;
                }

                device.BlendState = BlendState.Opaque;
                device.DepthStencilState = DepthStencilState.Default;
                device.RasterizerState = RasterizerState.CullCounterClockwise;

                mesh.Draw();
```

}

So moving on, in my update or input functions I would run an evaluative function to determine if LandscapeVertexY@CameraX is greater than a value of 5.

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand your question correctly you are trying to retrieve the rendered position of a vertex with by using a specified camera.

In this case you need to project the position of the vertex manually in your coordinate space by using matrix multiplication. This could be done by multiplying the position with your model-view-projection matrix. ( It can be done with the XNA matrix and vectors ).

Comment: Okay so how do I go about that?  In my draw() function I have these two bits of code:              `code` view = Matrix.CreateLookAt(cameraPosition,
                                              cameraPosition + cameraFront,
                                              Vector3.Up);

            projection = Matrix.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView(zoomAmount,
                                                                    device.Viewport.AspectRatio,
                                                                    1, 10000);`code`

Comment: As far as i know you have to multiply it in this order: Model * View * Projection, then multiply the vertex with the resulting matrix( There should be a method or maybe a overload for it ). You need to do this on each Vertex, but this would consume a lot of CPU, so the better idea is to use a bounding box or something else with less vertices.

Comment: Unfortunately a bounding box won't work for me since the model is similar to a maze.  SO i have added:              landscape = Content.Load<Model>("landscape");
            landscapeModelTransforms = new Matrix[landscape.Bones.Count];
            landscape.CopyAbsoluteBoneTransformsTo(landscapeModelTransforms);   So in my update function I do your multiplication, but how do I test for the values?

Comment: If you've multiplied the matrices with your vector the vector should contain the values you want for the camera.

Comment: hahah so frustrating,  I don't have a clue.  How do you get the matrix of the model?

Comment: This is the matrix of the model you are drawing, so everything like rotation, translation and scaling.